# Why os.listdir converts ┤ to \xa6 and how to convert it back?

Tags: python, python-2.7

When I run

```python
files = os.listdir(path)
```

it returns a list with the files in directory `path` and save it to `files`, the problem is that one of the files on directory `path` uses the box drawing charactere ┤ and when I print the list `files` I get this

```python
['l\xa6oli.txt', 'asd.txt']
```

the first string should be `'l┤oli.txt'` but it is `'l\xa6oli.txt'`.

I would like to convert the resulted string back to the one that contains the character `┤`instead of `\xa6`, also I would like to know what sort of encoding is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your string has the character you want in it. Python is simply displaying it with a hexadecimal escape for clarity; `\xa6` in a string literal means a byte with hex value A6, rather than a literal backslash, x, a, and 6. If you print the string:

```
print files[0]
```

it should display as a box-drawing character, at least on your system. Byte A6 might be something else on a different computer.